# How Amazon Glue can process large input files job

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, pyspark, large-files, aws-glue

I am creating an ETL automation pipeline using resources provided by Amazon
such as Amazon Glue for data transformation.

When I passed 1 MB JSON file, it transforms data successfully & provides an output in required JSON format.

I did R&D on how Amazon Glue processes larger files (2 GB), but didn't find the expected results. Could you please let me know if you have any idea/references regarding the same issue?

I am using PySpark custom script to do transformation stuff.